# Acessar página protegida por login com C#

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer um script para capturar links de uma página, acontece que essa página é protegida por login, tenho esse login mas não sei como fazer uma requisição para poder acessar essa página protegida. Seria algo assim:

- Acessar página (`https://nome-da-página`)
- Fazer o login usando email e senha (Nessa parte que eu estou com dificuldades, tenho esse email e essa senha, mas não estou como utilizar)
- Capturar link

Answer (score 1):

Se você vai fazer a requisição via C#, então uma das formas minimalistas de se fazer isso é com a classe [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.100).aspx).

Você pode autenticar usando as propriedades `Credentials` e `UseDefaultCredentials`.

Exemplo:

```
WebClient foo = new WebClient();
foo.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
foo.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("John Doe", "123456");
```

Daí você baixa o conteúdo assim:

```
string endereco = "https://nome-da-página/LinksQueVouRoubar";
string resposta = foo.DownloadString(endereco);
```

A string `resposta` vai conter todo o HTML do resultado. Agora é só garimpar.

Comment: em "string resposta = client.DownloadString(endereco);" aonde está a declaração de  .client ?

Comment: @EltonA.Pering é o mesmo que foi instanciado antes, editei para deixar mais claro.